# Get previous row value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to get a duration from my **postgresql** table and I have one idea on how to do it, is just to do **extract** from the time difference. But I can't get it right. Here is an example of table that I have.

| ID | Name | Status_from | Status_To | Change_Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Andrew | Ready | Break | 2021-04-28 04:46:34 |
| 2 | Andrew | Break | Meeting | 2021-07-30 10:50:04 |
| 3 | Andrew | Meeting | Checkout | 2021-07-30 10:50:06 |
| 4 | Nazar | Checkout | Ready | 2021-07-30 10:54:09 |
| 5 | Nazar | Ready | Meeting | 2021-07-30 11:03:09 |
| 6 | Andrew | Checkout | Ready | 2021-07-30 11:10:09 |

And here is an example of the output that I want to get

| ID | Name | Status_from | Status_To | Change_Time | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Andrew | NULL | Ready | 2021-07-30 10:29:04 | NULL (Or 0) |
| 2 | Andrew | Ready | Meeting | 2021-07-30 10:50:04 | 1260 |
| 3 | Andrew | Meeting | Checkout | 2021-07-30 10:50:06 | 2 |
| 4 | Nazar | NULL | Ready | 2021-07-30 10:54:09 | NULL (Or 0) |
| 5 | Nazar | Ready | Meeting | 2021-07-30 11:03:09 | 540 |
| 6 | Andrew | Checkout | Ready | 2021-07-30 11:10:09 | 1203 |

The duration is the time that **Status_to** become a **status_from** for the same **Name**
Any suggestions on how can I do it? Because I'm out of ideas, thank you in advance!

Comment: You want `LAG()` : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lag()` and then "epoch" arithmetic to get the difference in seconds:

```
select t.*,
       (extract(epoch from changetime) -
        extract(epoch from lag(changetime) over (partition by name order by changetime)
       ) as duration_seconds
from t;
```

Comment: That's perfect, Thank you so much!

Comment: @NazarHnid as it solved your problem, consider accepting the answer.